# How can I import LambdaContext?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm making AWS Lambda Function.
Now I want to `isinstance(context,LambdaContext)` , I'm expecting It works in AWS Lambda.
But I'm running unit test in local.

So How can I import LambdaContext.

Best

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack):

> LocalStack provides an easy-to-use test/mocking framework for developing Cloud applications.
>
> Currently, the focus is primarily on supporting the AWS cloud stack.
>
> LocalStack spins up the following core Cloud APIs on your local machine:
>
> > API Gateway at http://localhost:4567
> >
> > Kinesis at http://localhost:4568
> >
> > DynamoDB at http://localhost:4569
> >
> > DynamoDB Streams at http://localhost:4570
> >
> > Elasticsearch at http://localhost:4571
> >
> > S3 at http://localhost:4572
> >
> > Firehose at http://localhost:4573
> >
> > **Lambda at http://localhost:4574**
> >
> > SNS at http://localhost:4575
> >
> > SQS at http://localhost:4576
> >
> > Redshift at http://localhost:4577
> >
> > ES (Elasticsearch Service) at http://localhost:4578
> >
> > SES at http://localhost:4579
> >
> > Route53 at http://localhost:4580
> >
> > CloudFormation at http://localhost:4581
> >
> > CloudWatch at http://localhost:4582

Comment: Ho does this solve the OPs problem of creating a context object in unit tests explicitly? Not saying it doesn't just can't quite work out how it does.

Answer (score 4):

class LambdaContext defined in /var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py which is used to launch users functions and has the following structure:

```
class LambdaContext(object):
    def __init__(self, invokeid, context_objs, client_context, invoked_function_arn=None):
        self.aws_request_id = invokeid
        self.log_group_name = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME']
        self.log_stream_name = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME']
        self.function_name = os.environ["AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME"]
        self.memory_limit_in_mb = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE']
        self.function_version = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION']
        self.invoked_function_arn = invoked_function_arn

        self.client_context = make_obj_from_dict(ClientContext, client_context)
        if self.client_context is not None:
            self.client_context.client = make_obj_from_dict(Client, self.client_context.client)
        self.identity = make_obj_from_dict(CognitoIdentity, context_objs)

    def get_remaining_time_in_millis(self):
        return lambda_runtime.get_remaining_time()

    def log(self, msg):
        str_msg = str(msg)
        lambda_runtime.send_console_message(str_msg, byte_len(str_msg))
```

If you want to emulate it on your local environment, just add it into your script:

```
class ClientContext(object):
    __slots__ = ['custom', 'env', 'client']


def make_obj_from_dict(_class, _dict, fields=None):
    if _dict is None:
        return None
    obj = _class()
    set_obj_from_dict(obj, _dict)
    return obj


def set_obj_from_dict(obj, _dict, fields=None):
    if fields is None:
        fields = obj.__class__.__slots__
    for field in fields:
        setattr(obj, field, _dict.get(field, None))


class LambdaContext(object):
    def __init__(self, invokeid, context_objs, client_context, invoked_function_arn=None):
        self.aws_request_id = invokeid
        self.log_group_name = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME']
        self.log_stream_name = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME']
        self.function_name = os.environ["AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME"]
        self.memory_limit_in_mb = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE']
        self.function_version = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION']
        self.invoked_function_arn = invoked_function_arn

        self.client_context = make_obj_from_dict(ClientContext, client_context)
        if self.client_context is not None:
            self.client_context.client = None
        self.identity = None


    def get_remaining_time_in_millis(self):
        return None

    def log(self, msg):
        str_msg = str(msg)
        print(str_msg)
        # lambda_runtime.send_console_message(str_msg, byte_len(str_msg))
```

Comment: I think i understand this, but is it possible to link to some open source code that your refer to in `/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py`. Is this in an aws repository somewhere?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to have an example of how this was used in unittest?

Answer (score 4):

Just found [this package](https://pypi.org/project/aws-lambda-context/), it seems that someone made a pip package using the concepts from the other answers in this question.

Had the same issue, hope it helps whoever comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is not in the *strictest* sense an answer, please remove if unsuitable.

I have experimented with @Dmitry-Masanov 's answer, and have bodged a python fixture for pytest, which can be used either in the test script itself, or as I am doing, in the `conftest.py` file.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_lambda_context():
    class ClientContext:
        """
        Class for mocking Context

        Has `custom`, `env`, and `client` `__slots__`
        """

        __slots__ = ["custom", "env", "client"]

    def make_obj_from_dict(_class, _dict, fields=None):
        """
        Makes an object of `_class` from a `dict`

        :param _class: A class representing the context
        :type _class: `ContextClass`
        :param _dict: A dictionary of data 
        :type _dict: `dict`
        :param fields: [description], defaults to None
        :type fields: [type], optional
        :return: An object
        :rtype: `ClientContext` class
        """
        if _dict is None:
            return None
        obj = _class()
        set_obj_from_dict(obj, _dict)
        return obj

    def set_obj_from_dict(obj, _dict, fields=None):
        if fields is None:
            fields = obj.__class__.__slots__
        for field in fields:
            setattr(obj, field, _dict.get(field, None))

    class LambdaContext(object):
        """
        Create a Lambda Context Class object
        """

        def __init__(self, invokeid, client_context, invoked_function_arn=None):
            self.aws_request_id = invokeid
            self.log_group_name = "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME"
            self.log_stream_name = "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME"
            self.function_name = "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME"
            self.memory_limit_in_mb = "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE"
            self.function_version = "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION"
            self.invoked_function_arn = invoked_function_arn

            self.client_context = make_obj_from_dict(ClientContext, client_context)
            if self.client_context is not None:
                self.client_context.client = None
            self.identity = None

        def get_remaining_time_in_millis(self):
            return None

        def log(self, msg):
            str_msg = str(msg)
            print(str_msg)

    lambda_context = LambdaContext("AWS_ID", {})

    return lambda_context
```

I'm nearly certain my implementation can be improved (OO python isn't a strong skill of mine), but this serves my purpose of:

- mocking a lambda context object
- integrating with pytest

This can be used in a way similar to this:

```
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_lambda_handler(apigw_event, mock_lambda_context):
    ret = app.lambda_handler(apigw_event, mock_lambda_context)
    assert "log_stream_name" in ret["body"]
```

Thanks again Dmitry, your answer saved me a bunch of hassle.