# How to emulate locally aws context for testing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, pytest

I have created a lambda
where I retrieve region, based on the `context.invoked_function_arn`.

So, I would like to create and emulate this behavior using a test script file not via `conftest.py` because I have other unit test methods implemented in the same test script.

I find this link [lambda-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559331/how-can-i-import-lambdacontext) which is useful and implemented the same concept in my test script. However all the time, I'm getting the  `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'invoked_function_arn'`  error message.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_lambda_context():
    class ClientContext:
        """
        Class for mocking Context

        Has `custom`, `env`, and `client` `__slots__`
        """

        __slots__ = ["custom", "env", "client"]

    def make_obj_from_dict(_class, _dict, fields=None):
        """
        Makes an object of `_class` from a `dict`

        :param _class: A class representing the context
        :type _class: `ContextClass`
        :param _dict: A dictionary of data
        :type _dict: `dict`
        :param fields: [description], defaults to None
        :type fields: [type], optional
        :return: An object
        :rtype: `ClientContext` class
        """
        if _dict is None:
            return None
        obj = _class()
        set_obj_from_dict(obj, _dict)
        return obj

    def set_obj_from_dict(obj, _dict, fields=None):
        if fields is None:
            fields = obj.__class__.__slots__
        for field in fields:
            setattr(obj, field, _dict.get(field, None))

    class LambdaContext(object):
        """
        Create a Lambda Context Class object
        """

        def __init__(self, invokeid, client_context, invoked_function_arn=None):
            self.aws_request_id = invokeid
            self.log_group_name = "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME"
            self.log_stream_name = "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME"
            self.function_name = "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME"
            self.memory_limit_in_mb = "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE"
            self.function_version = "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION"
            self.invoked_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:" \
                                        "ExampleLambdaFunctionResourceName-AULC3LB8Q02F"

            self.client_context = make_obj_from_dict(ClientContext, client_context)
            if self.client_context is not None:
                self.client_context.client = None
            self.identity = None

        def get_remaining_time_in_millis(self):
            return None

        def log(self, msg):
            str_msg = str(msg)
            print(str_msg)

    context = LambdaContext("AWS_ID", {})

    return context

def test_handler(events, mock_lambda_context):
    res = handler(events, mock_lambda_context)
    assert res['context.invoked_function_arn'] == "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:ExampleLambdaFunctionResourceName-AULC3LB8Q02F"
```

Can anyone point me how to fix this silly one?

Comment: I figure it out some alternate way, but if someone has any comments on this approach let me know. In the mean time, I will post my alternate way as answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample_context.json like this:

```
{
    "invoked_function_arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:ExampleLambdaFunctionResourceName-AULC3LB8Q02F",
    "log_group_name": "/aws/lambda/ExampleLambdaFunctionResourceName-AULC3LB8Q02F",
    "function_name": "ExampleLambdaFunctionResourceName-AULC3LB8Q02F",
    "function_version": "$LATEST"
}
```

Then in my main test file:

```
    @pytest.fixture
    def context_outcome():
        return load_json_from_file('sample_context.json')
    
    
    @pytest.fixture
    def context(context_outcome):
        response = type('new', (object,), context_outcome)
        seqs = tuple, list, set, frozenset
        for i, j in context_outcome.items():
            if isinstance(j, dict):
                setattr(response, i, context(j))
            elif isinstance(j, seqs):
                setattr(response, i,
                        type(j)(context(sj) if isinstance(sj, dict) else sj for sj in j))
            else:
                setattr(response, i, j)
        return response

def test_main(events, context):
    assert context.invoked_function_arn == "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:ExampleLambdaFunctionResourceName-AULC3LB8Q02F"
```

Comment: Saved me ..... hours - surprised this isn't documented anywhere (unless my google skills failed). C# has a library (Amazon.Lambda.TestUtilities) which has a TestContext...

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by doing the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@pytest.fixture
def context():
    @dataclass
    class LambdaContext:
        function_name: str = "test"
        aws_request_id: str = "88888888-4444-4444-4444-121212121212"
        invoked_function_arn: str = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789101:function:test"


    return LambdaContext()

def test_lambda(context):
    my_class = MyClass(EVENT, context)
```